# Ubuntu 18.04 - After logging to my user not able to use keyboard or mouse, seems screen is hung

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, keyboard, mouse

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 in dual mode with windows 10. It was working fine. Today i installed some packages and last i installed virt-manager. Then after that I rebooted and from then I am facing issues. I am able to login the user but after that screen appears and gets hung. I am not able to use the mouse cursor or keyboard. I only can hard press the power button. I am using dell inspirion 15 7000. I also tried updating the nvidia driver from the ctrl+alt+f2 login terminal. Now even that terminal is not opening. KIndly suggest.

If I need to reinstall it how should I do it, since I cant delete the ubuntu as the grub is coming from it. I have my windows also running along with it.

THanks